# RuntimeError: Event loop is closed Task was destroyed but it is pending Discord Python

Tags: python, runtime, discord, python-asyncio, discord.py

Hi I have looked on several other forums and cannot diagnose my issue based on their code. This is for a discord bot, and whenever I get this error it forces the code to exit. It does not happen every time I run and I cannot figure out why or how to prevent it.
This is my code below:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):


    if message.content.startswith('!view'):
        old = message.content
        url = old.replace("!view", "").strip()
        print ("Viewer started")

        headers1 = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.91 Safari/537.36",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            }

        for i in range(100):
            try:
                r =  requests.get(url,headers=headers1,verify=False,timeout=5)
                if r.status_code == 99:
                    print("Viewed successfully")
                loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
                loop.close()
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

Thank you so much in advance, I am really puzzled!

Comment: Could you post the full error?

Comment: RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<Client._run_event() running at C:\Users\blake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py:307> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[BaseSelectorEventLoop._sock_connect_done(1108)(), <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000001A0BA3D9708>()]>>

Comment: Are you using `requests`?  You have to use aiohttp, because `requests` blocks the event loop. See: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean

Comment: Why are you getting the event loop object, only to close it immediately? This is what probably causes the "event loop was closed error".

Answer (score 1):

Most cases the problem is becouse you didn't created a bot in the aplication
https://discord.com/developers